# Цикл выводит не те значения, которые нужно

Tags: c#, циклы, консоль

У нас есть метод, который получает из параметров массив **NumberText**, примерно с таким содержимым: {"один", "четыре", "десять"...}. Условие в цикле сравнивает строки массива **NumberText** со строками массива **N**: если эти строки равны, то в массив **NumberNumeral** запишется значения массива **NN**. У массивов NN и N все числа и строки идут в одинаковой последовательности, поэтому в массив **NumberNumeral** должно записаться число, которое равно числу в строке массива **NumberText**. Однако, когда я ввожу "Один + пять", то мне выводит: "1 + **0**". Но если я введу "Один+два+три+четыре+пять", то мне выведет: "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5". Почему числа не выводятся как мне надо?

Я первый раз задаю вопрос на таких сайтах по программированию, поэтому надеюсь, что понятно описал мою проблему, а потому буду ждать вашей помощи

```
static void TransformNum(string[] NumberText)
    {
        string[] N = new string[] 
        { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять", "шесть", "семь", 
          "восемь", "девять", "десять", "одиннадцать", "двенадцать", 
          "тринадцать", "четырнадцать", "пятнадцать", "шестнадцать",
          "семнадцать", "восемнадцать", "девятнадцать", "двадцать", };

        int[] NN = new int[] 
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

        int[] NumberNumeral = new int[NumberText.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberText.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < NumberText.Length; b++)
            {
                if (NumberText[i] == N[b])
                {
                    NumberNumeral[i] = NN[b];
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < NumberNumeral.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NumberNumeral[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberText.Length; i++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < NumberText.Length; b++)
    {
        if (NumberText[i] == N[b])
        {
            NumberNumeral[i] = NN[b];
        }
    }
}
```

Внутренний цикл у вас сравнивает столько строк из `N`, сколько есть в вашем вводе, а не столько, сколько реально их лежит в `N`. Т.е. после "один" и "два" цикл заканчивается, найдя только "один". А ноль во второй позиции - от инициализации массива. Так что нужно исправить внутренний цикл, чтобы он прошёл по всем элементам массива `N`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberText.Length; i++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < N.Length; b++) # <- ИСПРАВЛЕНО ЗДЕСЬ
    {
        if (NumberText[i] == N[b])
        {
            NumberNumeral[i] = NN[b];
        }
    }
}
```